# In a bash script, how do I provide values contained in a text file to the switch of a program execution?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I would like to write a `bash` script in Linux that executes a program multiple times (e.g., 3 times) and that specifies a switch value based on a list of values provided in a text file.

For example, suppose that there is some program `programname` that has a switch `-switch` that takes a floating point number as input.  So, one execution of the program might read:

```
programname -switch 0.05
```

where 0.05 is a particular value passed to the switch `-switch`.

Now I would like to read in some sort of text file that has a list of values that I would like to pass, in succession, to `-switch` in separate calls of `programname`.  My text file `test.txt` might contain these data:

```
0.05
3.19
100.75
```

I would like to write a `bash` script that will read in the text file and effectively make these calls in succession:

```
programname -switch 0.05
programname -switch 3.19
programname -switch 100.75
```

I am thinking of something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..3}
do
programname -switch $x
done
```

But, what should I type in place of `$x`?  In other words, I am not sure how to read in `test.txt` and provide its contents, one-by-one, to `-switch` as the `for` loop runs.  Do you have any advice?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

values.txt:

```
0.05
3.19
100.75
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

counter=1
for value in $(cat values.txt)
do
    programname -switch $value -counter $counter
    counter=$(expr $counter + 1)
done
```

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't specify this in my original post, but unfortunately I do still need the integer counter `i`, because I will pass the value of `i` (i.e., `$i`) to `programname` in another switch (which I didn't specify in my question).  Is there any way that we can maintain `i`?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use any external utilities. The counter increment and `read` can be done together as shown or the counter increment can be moved anywhere within the loop.

```
while ((i++)); read -r value
do
    programname -switch "$value" -other "$i"
done < test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't quite seem to work for my application because `$value` and `$i` are in quotes: `"$value"` and `"$i"`.  Unfortunately, for my application, I need to pass in `$value` as a floating point (regular input), not as a string in quotation marks.

Comment: @Andrew: Your application will never see the quotes. The shell (Bash) uses them to protect the contents of the variable then removes them before passing the contents to the application.

Comment: If you need to pass the parameter as a floating point value rather than a string, you are out of luck.  The shell works with strings.  Even execvp takes only char * arguments, so you will have to work very hard to pass something other than a string.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: If you're talking about the binary representation of a floating point value, then it would be challenging. You could serialize it in some way. But there's no reason that the string representation can't be easily passed. In fact, that's just what the OP shows in the question.